# Java URLDecoder, Exception on Linux Server A, Working well on Linux Server B

Tags: java, linux, http, redhat

I've got problems tracing cause of this.

```
//check string if valid url
String input = sb.toString();
URLDecoder.decode(input, "UTF-8");
```

This works on Linux server A - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga):

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

But is not working on Linux server B - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago):

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.4) (rhel-1.41.1.10.4.el6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone suggests how to debug?

Additional info:

- Same jar used for servers A & B
- Passed same http request on both servers A & B, (except for the IP of course)
- Tried recompiling jar using jdk 5, 6, and 7 but still server B can't parse the http request. URLDecoder returns an Exception 'null'

As requested, the stacktrace: 
`java.nio.InvalidMarkException
        at java.nio.Buffer.reset(Buffer.java:297)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)`

Comment: You should define "Not working"

Comment: hi, revised the question, thanks

Comment: Your server B has OpenJDK Runtim but server A not. That might be an issue

Comment: You should post a full stacktrace

Comment: hi, added stacktrace in the question, but omitted some lines due confidentiality. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try-catch and print error message.
(If you show error message, maybe I solve the problem.)
Open JDK and Oracle JDK is not same operation in whole system.

And show input string (encode string).

Comment: hi, added stacktrace in the question, but omitted some lines due confidentiality. Thanks

Comment: Maybe Open JDK and Oracle JDK are not same work. Check encode input string. One of way, You encode normal string on the other server. Maybe two servers result is not same.

Comment: hi i'll check with the java -version. will keep you posted